# Cannot Run Pip in Python 2.7.10

Tags: python-2.7, pip

I have Python 2.7.10 in Windows 7 32-bit. I cannot run pip in PowerShell. I have already added Python to my path as `C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\;C:\Python27\Scripts\;` Can anybody help?

[image]

Comment: You are trying to run a PowerShell command `pip` inside a Python interpreter. The Python interpreter is complaining that it has no idea what you are asking it to do.

Answer (score 0):

I ran pip in the PowerShell prompt and it worked! Thanks @msw.